# Question in a single page

Tags: exercises

I am using the exercise package. There is an exercise consisting of multiple questions. I would like each of the questions to not be broken in separate pages. Often I have the beginning of the question at the end of one page, and the subQuestion appear in the next one. Is there a way to force the question to be moved to the next page when this happens?

EDIT: I tried using minipage, with this code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, exercise}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[label=Ex1]
You have 60 minutes to complete this part

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\Question {\textit{[2 marks]} Simplify the following expressions}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \subQuestion {$ 2 \times 3x + 5x \times 2 $}
    \subQuestion {$ 6y^2 \times 2y - 5y +y \times 2 $}
    \EndCurrentsubQuestion
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\endminipage ...pagefalse \color@endgroup \egroup\expandafter \@iiiparbox \... \end{minipage}
```

Comment: maybe wrapping the question inside a minipage? can you please post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I had actually tried it after reading another post here, but I get an error. I have edited my question to include a snippet of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> An answer to the original question:

You were missing a `\EndCurrentQuestion`, and so a version which compiles is:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,exercise,multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}[label=Ex1]
You have 60 minutes to complete this part

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\Question {\textit{[2 marks]} Simplify the following expressions}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subQuestion {$ 2 \times 3x + 5x \times 2 $}
\subQuestion {$ 6y^2 \times 2y - 5y +y \times 2 $}
\EndCurrentsubQuestion
\end{multicols}
\EndCurrentQuestion
\end{minipage}
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

Notice I have also added the top alignment `[t]` to the minipage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. now I don't get the error, but this resets the question number.

Comment: @jrglez that's a new question then...

Comment: The exercise has multiple numbered questions. I don't mind if the exercise is broken into different pages, but I would like always have each question in a single page. For something like that I would have to wrap each question separately, but then the numbering is not consistent

Comment: @jrglez please then provide a MWE showing this problem/difficulty, as this is not really shown (as far as I can tell) in the OP. This seems like a whole new question, rather than evolving/iterating this question.

Comment: I will edit the question, but I would assume that keeping the question numbering was implied in the question.

Comment: @jrglez editing the question turns it into a whole new question, very different from the question originally asked. Just ask a new question.

Comment: I give up. Thank you for the help, but this site seems to spend more time telling people how they asked the question in correctly than actually solving questions.
As I said, I don't think that wanting to have a consisten question numbering makes this a completely new question, it's a pretty logical requirement

Comment: @jrglez If you want each question on a single page why not put `\clearpage` after each question which would make the next question start on a new page. If you have visited the site enough times to think that we spend more time telling people about asking their question incorrectly than providing answers then you should know how to ask a question. --- GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson Because I don't want one question per page, I want each question to be in a single page. If 7 questions fit in a page, perfect, the only thing I don't want is one question split in two separate pages. 
But maybe the title of my question is not clear enough. Can you please help me and tell me how I should have phrased it? I am not an English native speaker nor an Latex expert.

Comment: @oliversm I have unedited my question and created a completely new one

Comment: @jrglez do comment a link and I may have a look at it.

Comment: @oliversm No worries, thanks